# Replacing certain "<" and ">" in html string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
<table class="sentinelresultitems" style="width: 800px; font-size: 0.5em; margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 50px; margin-right: 50px; display: table;">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>
            <b>License ID</b>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: right">
            <b>Product</b>
        </td>
     /tr>
    <tr>
        <td>New</td>
        <td class="quoteproductname" style="text-align: right">Product > name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>New</td><td class="quoteproductname" style="text-align: right">Another < product name
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Im trying to generate a PDF out of the html string above in c#. But it crashes because i cant separate the `<` and `>` in the product name, thus resulting in invalid html. And even if i replace them with `&gt;` etc, they will still be parsed as `>`.

Is it possible to replace the `<` and `>` with something like `GT` and `LT` until i get it on the server? After that i can just do a normal text replace on that. Otherwise i will obviously replace all the tags as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is this related to javascript? Are you posting this HTML string via ajax?

Comment: Not sure if it is just a typo in the example, but you actually have invalid markup in your example (your first closing tr). If it isn't a typo, maybe it could be part of the problem.

Comment: If you did replace with `&gt;` why don't you replace with something like `__MYGT__` ?

Comment: @David Yes, i didnt want to write `var html = ...` above because it would mess upp the colors.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson Thanks but it doesnt matter in this case. I just want to replace the two `< >`

Comment: @MihaiIorga Because i only want to replace the two `< >` that im talking about, otherwise the html tags would be ruined as well

Comment: But you said you would replace back on server ...

Comment: @MihaiIorga Yes, but how am i supposed to replace only the 2 characters `< >` and not all om them in the html?

Comment: You say that if you use the entity codes (ie `&gt;`), it gets parsed as `>`, but you don't explain why this is. Any decent system should interpret them differently. Are you decoding the entities somewhere along the line?

Answer (score 0):

That's what you want ?

```
var replacers = {
    '<': 'GT',
    '>': 'LT'
};
var html = $('.sentinelresultitems').html().replace(/[<>]/g, function(match) {
    return replacers[match];
});
```

Comment: Hmm, this would replace all of my <>. I only want to replace the ones in the ` $('.sentinelresultitems')` text. Sorry for not beeing clear